# MySQL - What's wrong with the WHERE clause in my JOIN query?

Tags: mysql, date, where-clause

I managed to cobble together a join statement to give me a single table that displays my entire database. Now I need to narrow the results down to just the last 30 days, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to work this restriction into the query.

Right now I have:

```
select customers.name, customers.email, orderinfo.orderno, orderinfo.orderdate, status.state, orderinfo.lastupdate 
from customers 
where orderinfo.orderdate = curdate() 
inner join orderinfo on customers.id=orderinfo.fk_id 
inner join status on orderinfo.fk_code=status.code 
order by customers.name;
```

...in an attempt to just narrow it down to showing me all the records for today, but even that is not working. I see there are a variety of ways of doing the 30-day thing but the part I'm having the most trouble with is just getting the WHERE clause to work at all in this query.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WHERE` clause needs to go before the `ORDER BY`and after all joins.

```
select customers.name, customers.email, orderinfo.orderno, orderinfo.orderdate, status.state, orderinfo.lastupdate 
from customers 
inner join orderinfo on customers.id=orderinfo.fk_id 
inner join status on orderinfo.fk_code=status.code 
where orderinfo.orderdate = curdate() 
order by customers.name;
```

Comment: I knew it would be something simple. Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure ivan - glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the `orderinfo` in your `FROM` part.

```
select customers.name, customers.email, orderinfo.orderno, orderinfo.orderdate, status.state, orderinfo.lastupdate 
from customers 
inner join orderinfo on customers.id=orderinfo.fk_id 
inner join status on orderinfo.fk_code=status.code 
where orderinfo.orderdate = curdate() 
order by customers.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT customers.name, customers.email, orderinfo.orderno, orderinfo.orderdate, status.state, orderinfo.lastupdate 
FROM customers 
INNER JOIN orderinfo ON customers.id=orderinfo.fk_id 
INNER JOIN status ON orderinfo.fk_code=status.code 
WHERE orderinfo.orderdate = curdate() 
ORDER BY customers.name;
```

`WHERE` needs to be after all `JOINS` and before `ORDER BY`

Answer (score 0):

Your inner joins should come before your where clause

```
select customers.name, customers.email, orderinfo.orderno, orderinfo.orderdate, status.state, orderinfo.lastupdate 
from customers 
inner join orderinfo on customers.id=orderinfo.fk_id 
inner join status on orderinfo.fk_code=status.code 
where orderinfo.orderdate = curdate() 
order by customers.name;
```

If you need to do the query with the condition first, then you need subquery

```
Select * From
(
   select customers.name, customers.email, orderinfo.orderno, orderinfo.orderdate, status.state, orderinfo.lastupdate 
   from customers
   where orderinfo.orderdate = curdate()  
) customers
inner join orderinfo on customers.id=orderinfo.fk_id 
inner join status on orderinfo.fk_code=status.code 
order by customers.name;
```